# GKTurnBasedMatch Invite is declined by game center

Tags: game-center, ios9.2, gkturnbasedmatch, letterpress

I am developing 2 player Turn based game using game center. I have create a match by inviting my friend using game center view controller. I have played my turn after few seconds i got response the invite was declined (checked on log). I thought the reason behind was my friend didn't have my game on his devices, So he didn't get invite notification.

But I have tested letterpress Game as same above my friend, He got invite notification while clicks on notification its navigated to app store letterpress game page on device to force to download the letterpress app. From my side the match status showing awaiting for my frinds turn.  If player doesn't have letterpress game, he is getting notification and  the match notification didn't decline by game center.  Does letterpress game integrated with iOS Game center. How is letterpress game getting invite notification?

Can anyone please Guide me on this issues?

Answer (score 0):

You say you're developing a game, but I'm not clear if you have publicly released it yet? If not, then I'm not surprised that invitee's gamecenter would issue an auto-decline since there's no app on the appstore for it to download.

For pre-release testing, I've had really good results distributing my apps using Testflight. It's reasonably easy to add builds to Testflight, it's reasonably easy to manage the list of recipients, and it's quite easy to notify your testers when new builds are available. On their end, it's easy to open the Testflight app and install the new build.

Comment: I am also using Testflight for testing Builds. I am not released publicly yet. Still waiting for developer release.